# How does Heisenberg's matrix mechanics explain radition from electron inside the atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

How is radiation from an electron (which is inside an atom) explained
in matrix mechanics?

Is there any standard book available on matrix mechanics?

Comment: For qn 4.) Because matrix mechanics is an absolute pain whereas wave mechanics is easier to compute.

Comment: To re-open this question, ask only [one question per post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6833/2451).